# I need to add an EditText field with relative button when clicking on a "+" button

Tags: android, layout, button, onclick, layout-inflater

probably the title of my question is not really clear.
I'm developing my first Android Application for a University project. What I need now is to give the possibility of entering one "ingredient" to my users in order to look for recipes in a database. This is easy.

I read probably all the similar posts on this website but I couldn't solve my problem: now I want to give the user the possibility of specifying more than one ingredient so that there should be a "+" button below my first EditText field allowing to add new EditText fields between the first and the button itself.
Together with the EditText field I need a "-" button that, when clicked, "hide" the relative input field.

I hope the description is clear.

What I have now is my main XML layout and the second one, with edittext and "-"button...but I didn't understand how to push/inflate/show this layout in the main one...

Could you please help me?
This isthe layout I want to push:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ingredient"
    android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:id="@+id/newLine1">

 <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/ingredient"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/hint_ingredient" />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/remove"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/remove"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ingredient"
        android:onClick="removeLine"
    />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the main layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_linear">


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip" 
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_weight="1.0" android:fadingEdge="none">



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ingredients">

 <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/ingredient"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/hint_ingredient" />





</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/buttons">

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add"
    />

   <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/add"

        android:text="@string/search" 

        />
   </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

What about removing the new lines added by the inflator?

For now I solved like this:

```
public void removeLine(View v)
    {
        View line = (View) v.getParent();
        line.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

In the onClickListener for your "+" button you'll need to use a LayoutInflater to inflate your ingredient layout into a View.  Then use findViewById() to get a reference to your ingredients RelativeLayout and add the new View to it.

Make sure that you specify LayoutParams for the new view that is inflated.

You may want to change ingredients to a LinearLayout.  It is easier to add views to it than a RelativeLayout because you can just add views to a LinearLayout without having to worry about their relative position.

Good luck.

Comment: How I have another question.
The inflate works perfectly and I can add dynamically what I want. Now , as I described In my first post, I need to wire the "-" button next to every edittext field inflated. How do I do?
I couldn't find similar issues...

Comment: First, you need to give each inflated view an id (setId()), that way you can retrieve and reomve it.  Set the tag of each button with the remove id to the id of the inflated view.  You then need to set onclicklistner each time for the button with the id remove.  In your onclick method, check to see if the view had the id remove, and then if so get the tag and use it to remove the view.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

in the onClickListener to your '+' button write something like this :

```
int et_counter=1;
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

EditText et = new EditText(RecipeActivity.this);
//assign them an ID with an int counter
//use this counter later to refer to the EditText
//to retrieve the values
et.setId(et_counter);

ll.addView(et);
```

you could retrieve values like this :

```
for (n = 1; n <= et_counter; n++){
    et = (EditText) findViewById(n);
    String ingridient=et.getText().toString();
    //use the text somewhere
}
```

Similarly you can assign an onClick listener to your '-' button, refer to the EditText with the ID using et_counter and remove it using `et.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

You should be able to use this with your logic. Good Luck :-)